# Swift - Capturing RAW Image with zoomFactor crashes the app

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm having troubles taking RAW pictures with a `zoomFactor` different than `1.0`.
In fact if I take a picture with the minimum zoom level everything works fine. However, if I try to zoom closer to a subject changing the `zoomFactor` the app crashes with the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:] When specifying Bayer raw capture, the videoZoomFactor of the video device must be set to 1.0'

This only happens when shooting RAW. If I shoot using the standard HEVC format everything works. I'm using Swift 4.2 and the AVFoundation Framework

Here's the code referenced by the error:

```
extension CameraController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

public func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    guard error == nil else {
        print("Error capturing photo: \(error!)")
        return
    }
    
    // Access the file data representation of this photo.
    guard let photoData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else {
        print("No photo data to write.")
        return
    }
    
    print("Generating IMAGE with metadata \n", photo.metadata)
    
    
    if photo.isRawPhoto {
        // Generate a unique URL to write the RAW file.
        rawFileURL = makeUniqueDNGFileURL()
        do {
            // Write the RAW (DNG) file data to a URL.
            try photoData.write(to: rawFileURL!)
            print("RAW-URL Generated")
            createRAWImageOnAlbum(withRAWURL: rawFileURL!)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Couldn't write DNG file to the URL.")
        }
    } else {
        createHEVCPhotoOnAlbum(photo: photo)
    }
}

private func makeUniqueDNGFileURL() -> URL {
    let tempDir = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
    let fileName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
    return tempDir.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("dng")
}
```

}

Do you know the reason of this?

I'm setting the `zoomFactor` here:

```
    func updateZoom(toValue: CGFloat) throws {
    let session = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .unspecified)
    
    guard let cameras = (session.devices.compactMap { $0 }) as? [AVCaptureDevice], !cameras.isEmpty else { throw CameraControllerError.noCamerasAvailable }
    
    for camera in cameras {
        if camera.position == .back {
            self.rearCamera = camera
            try camera.lockForConfiguration()
            camera.ramp(toVideoZoomFactor: toValue, withRate: 4)
            camera.unlockForConfiguration()
        } else if camera.position == .front {
            self.frontCamera = camera
            try camera.lockForConfiguration()
            camera.ramp(toVideoZoomFactor: toValue, withRate: 4)
            camera.unlockForConfiguration()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where and how are you setting `zoomFactor`?

Comment: Check the max zoom supported by the device 'maxAvailableVideoZoomFactor'. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/2865758-maxavailablevideozoomfactor

Comment: I've updated the question with the new code

Comment: Why don't you just check if 'toValue' exceeds `videoMaxZoomFactor`?

Answer (score 0):

Do check the supporting zoom factor of the device, wherein `captureDevice` is your `AVCaptureDevice` instance:

```
func checkZoom(zoomFactor: CGFloat) {
    
    guard
        zoomFactor <= captureDevice.maxAvailableVideoZoomFactor,
        zoomFactor >= captureDevice.minAvailableVideoZoomFactor
    else {
        print("ZoomFactor not supported \(zoomFactor)")
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and it only confirms that I'm working in the right zoom scale range as "ZoomFactor not supported" is never printed. The strange thing to me here is that the error is only thrown if shooting RAW

Comment: so it crashes when calling the ramp() method.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you. It seems you can not specify the zoom factor on the device that doesn't support Apple ProRAW. If your device supports ProRAW, then it's OK to use the zoom factor directly.
Otherwise you need to crop the output image manually.